# Babel - Npm run script with --watch flag

Tags: npm, babeljs

So I am wanting to use babel to compile my jsx files on save so the following cli works

babel --presets es2015,react --extensions ".jsx" "ui/app/" --out-dir "ui/app/" --watch

I have babel watch for changes to jsx files and compiles them in place to js files.

Works great.

However if I put that into a npm script block it just hangs and doesn't compile files.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "babel-watch": "babel --presets es2015,react --extensions '.jsx' 'ui/app/' --out-dir 'ui/app/' --watch
}
...

Junior@Caldeum MINGW64 ~/Dropbox/SVN/insight_JSPM
$ npm run babel-watch

> babel --presets es2015,react --extensions ".jsx" "ui/app/" --out-dir "ui/app/" --watch

_
```

Is it possible that I'm missing something here. The command works just fine, but only when ran with npm run it does not.

Comment: I'm not sure the `--extensions` option applies to the `babel` command. Usually we recommend using two separate directories. What's the motivation for compiling back to the same place?

Comment: In this case it's to build the jsx files on save as I don't run the babel runtime. The extensions is meant to only target jsx files as that's all I'm monitoring at this time. We have separate build steps that do bundling of directories and we keep all source files in their respective module directories.